# Triggering a back button in webview

Tags: javascript, mobile, titanium, appcelerator

I'm using titanium studio to package an app we are currently working on, and one of the pages is a webview to a mobile version of our site. This all works and looks great, but when the user navigates to a new url, going backwards is impossible. I've tried several methods to set up a back button/ navigation group to solve this problem, but nothing seems to work. What would be the best way to either to load the next page into the nav group, or trigger a back button to appear upon a new page being loaded?

So far I have tried:

- Creating a navigation group and firing an event upon opening a new
  window to add it as a child.
- Creating a button and removing/adding it depending on `canGoBack()`
- Having a constant button exist that only    fires if `goBack()` is
  defined

Comment: A better [formatted question](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and code will help you get more answers.

Comment: Perhaps if explained *what* methods you've tried and *why* they failed to meet your requirements then we might be able to advise on a better approach.

Comment: more information is definitely need here, not sure if you are trying to navigate the webview back or the application back

Answer (score 3):

```
var btnBack = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title : '< ',
    top : 0,
    left : 0,
    height : '10%',
});
var btnFwd = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title : ' >',
    top : 0,
    right : 0,
    height : '10%',
});
var webView = Titanium.UI.createWebView({
    url : 'http://gooogle.com',
    canGoBack : true,
    canGoForward : true,
    top : '10%',
    height : '90%',
});
btnBack.addEventListener('click', function() {
    webView.goBack();
});
btnFwd.addEventListener('click', function() {
    webView.goForward();
});
var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
    backgroundColor:'#fff',
});
win1.add(btnBack);
win1.add(btnFwd);
win1.add(webView);
win1.open();
```

Does this solve your issue? if this doesn't, please clarify what do you need to do??